# How to make a deep copy of Object with get and set operators in JS

Tags: javascript

I hope you'll help me.

I want to make a deep copy of this object User.

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj)
        return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr))
            copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
  return copy;
}

var User = {
    _firstName: 'robert',

    get firstName() {
        return this._firstName;
    },
    set firstName(val) {
        this._firstName = val;
    },

    affFirstName: function() {
        console.log(this._firstName);
    },
};

console.log(User);
var User2 = clone(User);    
console.log(User2);
```

This function clone doesn't work (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn6Zw/) for example)

This copy creates new variable with the name of get and set.

Set and get Operators are not copied.

But the function affFirstName() is well copied.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: Minor issue: Use `new obj.constructor();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ES5, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` to get a copy of the getters and setters that may exist on an object.

You can then pass those descriptors to `Object.defineProperty` to recreate them on a new object.

Note that if those getters or setters rely on lexically scoped variables the new clone will share those variables with the original object.  The new object will *not* get its own copy of those variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
function clone(obj) {
  if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj)
    return obj;
  var copy = obj.constructor();
  for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, attr).value instanceof Object) {
        copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
      }
      else {
        Object.defineProperty(copy, attr, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,attr));
      }
    }
  }
  return copy;
}
```

The corrected clone function to make a deep copy with operators get and set.